# How do I center a <svg> in <body> based on screen width/height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, d3.js

I did some [research](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437786/how-to-get-web-page-size-browser-window-size-screen-size-in-a-cross-browser-wa) on the matter, but it doesn't seem to be working.

I want to be able to make a `<svg>` container that encompasses the entire screen of the browser (aka everything that isn't a tab, toolbar, etc. etc.).

[image: Here's a picture]

So if you look at the picture, I want the `<svg>` to occupy everything below the tab toolbar to the bottom of the page (is it the viewport or window?)—aka everything in the red box.

Here's the code I have so far (just the `<script />`):

```
<script>
function startThePage(){
  var height = $(document).height();
  var width  = $(document).width();

  var svgSelection = 
    d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height);

  var myCircle = svgSelection
      .append("circle")
      .attr("cx", (width/2))
      .attr("cy", (height/2))
      .attr("r", 22)
      .style("fill", "lightgray")
      .style("stroke", "gray");

};
//alert(window.screen.availWidth);
//alert(window.screen.availHeight);

</script>
```

For some reason this seems to make the document slightly bigger, meaning the user can scroll back and forth (for now there's just a filler circle in it, which I want to center). This puts the circle out of center. How do I fix that?

Comment: I had this same problem a year ago when I started with D3. I'm pretty sure you just need to remove the margin and padding from the body. That should give you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I think `box-sizing:border-box`, `margin:0;padding:0;`, and `overflow:hidden` should cover mostly everything...

Answer (score 0):

In order to manipulate the circle, i think you need to play with the

```
.attr("cx", (width/2))
.attr("cy", (height/2))
```

values and as far as raising the cx value to be approx half of the screen width. Then you can set the cy value to approx 20 or so. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

In order to center your circle on the x-axis, you have to set the `margin-right:auto;` and `margin-left:auto;` That will center your circle on the x-axis. As for your `<svg>`, make sure the html and body elements have the following attributes:

```
html, body {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
```

Then make sure your `<svg>` has the following attributes:

```
svg {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
```

That should center your circle and properly fill the `<svg>` to the entire screen.